# How to use Vue.js methods to set data properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to display data that is requested from a server. I have created a new Vue app and defined a method:

```
methods: {
  getData: function() {
    // making a request, parsing the response and pushing it to the array.
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
    }
  }
```

The method works OK and I can log the array to the console on a button click.

```
<button v-on:click="getData">Get me some data</button>
```

However, I'm not sure how to actually use this array in the app. I would like save it to a property and then display it for the user. At first, I was thinking that I could use computed properties like this:

```
computed: {
  values: function() {
    return this.getData;
  }
}
```

... and display it to the user with a `for` loop:

```
<p v-for="value in values">{{ value }}></p>
```

At least this solution did not produce the desired result. I've probably misunderstood some of Vue's logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data property.

```
data() {
   return {
       values: []
   }
},

methods: {
   getData: function() {
       this.values = arr;
   }
}
```

And loop the values

Comment: Thanks, this works and I can see from the console that the `values` array is updated accordingly. However, it seems that Vue cannot detect these changes to an array and the fetched values are not displayed on front-end (just showing the initial, empty array). Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you sure you have assigned the fetched data to the values?

Comment: Yes, I changed the logic as follows.

```
  data() {
   return {
     values: []
   }
  },
  methods: {
   getData: function() {
     this.values = arr;
     console.log(this.values); // I can see the fetched data on console.
   }
}
```
I think that the problem is that my app doesn't re-render the HTML document when the `values` array is updated.
`<p v-for="value in values">{{ value }}></p>`
This is just displaying the initial array, not the updated.

Comment: It took a while to debug but the problem was in scope. `this.values = arr; console.log(this.values);` This worked OK in the scope of the function, but `this` wasn't referring to the array I was thinking of. Needed to add `const self = this;` on global level. It was hard to notice that but works OK now.l